# Disabling One-Finger Tap-to-Click But Keep Two-Finger tap Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

The option to disable the touchpad while typing does not work on my Samsung RC512 with an Elantech touchpad and I enjoy two-finger scroll and middle-click emulation with two fingers too much to disable tapping the touchpad. When I type the cursor will jump around because I'll hit the touchpad with my palm.  How can I disable one-finger tapping but keep multi-finger tapping?

Answer (score 3):

```
synclient TapButton1=0
```

- TapButton1 means 1-finger tap.
- 0 means do nothing.

Comment: Is this persisted across sessions?

Comment: Nice nice, but which file should I edit?

Comment: I know I solved this years ago on my old Mint 13. But now I am trying with a Live CD for Mint 17 "Rebecca". Nice thing is, there is now a GUI to configure these touchpad options. But in the GUI you can't have 2-tap or 3-tap without 1-tap. I am wondering where these settings are written.

Comment: This will probably be less effective in 17.04 and higher where libinput is taking over, in that case you will use libinput-list-devices and modify the Xorg config (or use the Control Panel options). If you don't see the Mouse/Touchpad in the Control Panel try removing the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics package if you DO have the xserver-xorg-input-libinput package installed.)

Answer (score 2):

xinput will allow you to manipulate the properties of human interface devices. It will also show you what human interface devices are there, and some parameters for manipulating them, such as their name and id.

```
xinput
```

Shows you a list of devices, I have an Elantech touchpad that shows up as `ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]`. You should run the command to see the same, but I'll phrase my answer using the output that I see.

```
xinput list-props 12
```

Shows me the available properties for item id 12, which you can see decriptions for in the [Synaptics Man Page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html).

There looks like there could be multiple strategies for doing what you're looking for, but the property `Synaptics Tap Action (327)` looks promising and the man page says to set this to 0 to disable.

```
 xinput set-prop 12 327 0
```

where 12 is the device's id as shown by `xinput` and 327 is the property number as seen in `xinput list-props 12`