# How to disable physical touchpad buttons but keep tap as click

Tags: touchpad, xinput, button, tap-to-click

My old laptop (Samsung np300v3a, running fresh Ubuntu 18.04) has a broken left trackpad button, that is always pressed. I have been trying to disable the physical keys, but keep the tap to click in order to retain this use of the trackpad.

I've tried modifying xinput button-map, set-props, and some synclient options. I can disable the left click with xinput, but this also disables the tap to click function.

Threads I've read:
[Disabling One-Finger Tap-to-Click But Keep Two-Finger tap Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161420/disabling-one-finger-tap-to-click-but-keep-two-finger-tap-ubuntu-12-04)
[How to disable physical mouse buttons below touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725607/how-to-disable-physical-mouse-buttons-below-touchpad)

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to at least Ubuntu 18.10 or 19.04, there is a simple way :

create the file (and the directory) :

/etc/libinput/local-overrides.quirks

put in it this :

```
[disable physical button of touchpad]
MatchUdevType=touchpad
MatchBus=ps2
AttrEventCodeDisable=BTN_LEFT
```

It work fine on my sony vaio pro 13.
You may have to tweak the Match* lines, have a look at :
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/1.13.0/device-configuration-via-udev.html

good luck